# Why does nesting a bunch of blocks causes a stack overflow in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, stack-overflow

The code `{}` is perfectly legal in JavaScript as it represents a [Block](http://es5.github.io/#x12.1).

However, I noticed that nesting a lot of blocks (`{{...}}`) inside another raises in Chrome*:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

**Why** is a stack overflow happening here?

---

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LIofu) illustrating the issue (jsfiddle crashes).

When asking in the JSRoom [Zirak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/617762/zirak) found out that the magic number is **3913** blocks on chrome and **2555** on Firefox.

What is being pushed to the stack? Why?

---

(*) I've checked and it also happens in IE and Firefox

Update: I've checked and unreliably IE is able to avoid the stack overflow exception. It has thrown it two times but not the third. If any of the readers have IE and are willing to test older versions of it too (like IE8 and 9) and let me know what happens I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: How do you run a codepen ?

Comment: I'm guessing the "{" allocates a new stack frame for the block, since you could be declaring new variables inside it, and there's a browser limit on the stack size to prevent out of memory errors.

Comment: @faffaffaff Why does it create a stack frame as it's not a possible scope ?

Comment: What makes you say it's not a scope?

Comment: @faffaffaff Javascript doesn't have block scope.

Comment: @dystroy It runs on its own, you need to open the developer tools to see the errors. F12 and switch to script.

Comment: @Paulpro That's almost correct. JavaScript does have block scope, but only in `try/catch` and `with`. Which are not the case here

Comment: Maybe the parser is recursing whenever it sees a `{`?

Comment: They may be implementing it with scope potential in preparation for `let`. In Firefox, a statement block *can* create variable scope. Technically it's more correct to say JavaScript *has* block scope, but ECMAScript 5 and lower doesn't.

Comment: We can make many guesses. What would be interesting is something a little more concrete.

Comment: @CrazyTrain This is an interesting idea, if I had to guess `let` would be my guess too but I was unable to find any reference to support it.

Comment: If you pass enough expressions to the comma operator, you also get a Stack Overflow error (see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cHIga). Something tells me the cause is the same.

Comment: just tested it in node.js. It also produces a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" Error (as it was to expect) but it gives some extra information: `var compiledWrapper = runInThisContext(wrapper, filename, true)` (module.js:439) --> this is where the exception is thrown.

Comment: @basilikum: That's NodeJS's `eval()` call that invokes the module code.

Comment: Just compiled the code using v8, using the disassembler, and it's clearly not about execution. I got the RangeError exception, during the compilation (probably the parsing). This confirms ghord's answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all, ghord is completely correct. It is caused by the parser's recursive nature, so give him upvote love. But proof needs to be had, and OP wanted me to post this as a separate answer.

### Firefox

So, where to find out about how it was done? Ask some guys who're in the engine making. So I went over to the `#jsapi` channel on `irc://irc.mozilla.org` and asked them:

> `< bhackett> zirak: well, with a recursive descent parser all the productions will roughly correspond to a frame on the C stack`
>
> `< bhackett> zirak: the parser is at js/src/frontent/Parser.cpp`
>
> `< Waldo> zirak: Parser<ParseHandler>::statement(bool canHaveDirectives) and Parser<ParseHandler>::statements() pretty much`
>
> `< bhackett> zirak: in this case, the recursion will be Parser::blockStatement ->Parser::statements -> Parser::statement -> Parser::blockStatement`

Which is pretty much the answer. Going to the mozilla-central repository and digging in, we have our suspects:

- [`Parser<ParseHandler>::blockStatement`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/5769b3e238ff/js/src/frontend/Parser.cpp#l3295)
- [`Parser<ParseHandler>::statements`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/5769b3e238ff/js/src/frontend/Parser.cpp#l2460)

So, what we have is this:

- `statements` which calls `blockStatement`, which parses the block, to find another block, calling

  - `statements` which calls `blockStatement`, which parses the block, to find another block, calling

    - `statements` which calls `blockStatement`, which parses the block, to find another block, calling

      - ...

Until the stack collapses, I'm guessing [here](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/5769b3e238ff/js/src/frontend/Parser.cpp#l2462).

So we have the source for Firefox.

### Chrome/Chromium/anything else based on v8

Learning my lesson from Firefox, I went to the v8 project and looked for a file named `parser`. Sure enough, it was there!

The next thing was looking for when a block is parsed, so I naively searched for `statements`, arriving on the promising [ParseStatement](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/parser.cc?r=15100#1339).

And it's our lucky day, a giant `switch`! And [the first case](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/parser.cc?r=15100#1368) is what we care about, a call to `ParseBlock`, another promising name!

Indeed, [inside `ParseBlock`, we find a call](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/parser.cc?r=15100#1757) to `ParseStatement`. So, to be clear, we have two functions:

- [`Parser::ParseBlock`](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/parser.cc?r=15100#1743)
- [`Parser::Parser::ParseStatement`](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/parser.cc?r=15100#1339)

And they're calling each other like we saw in Firefox:

- `ParseStatement` which calls `ParseBlock`, which parses the block, to find another block, calling

  - `ParseStatement` which calls `ParseBlock`, which parses the block, to find another block, calling

    - `ParseStatement` which calls `ParseBlock`, which parses the block, to find another block, calling

      - ...

Until kaboom goes the stack.

### Safari

(Sorry for calling it closed-source in the last edit!) Safari's js engine is [JavaScriptCore](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/JavaScriptCore), which resides in the WebKit project. Finding the functions was pretty much the same as finding them for Chrome, so let's skip to the interesting part:

- [`Parser<LexerType>::parseSourceElements`](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/JavaScriptCore/parser/Parser.cpp?rev=151869#L157)
- [`Parser<LexerType>::parseStatement`](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/JavaScriptCore/parser/Parser.cpp?rev=151869#L708)
- [`Parser<LexerType>::parseBlockStatement`](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/JavaScriptCore/parser/Parser.cpp?rev=151869#L690)

We have an extra function in the middle, but the principle is the same:

- `parseSourceElements` which calls `parseStatement` which calls `parseBlockStatement`, which parses the block, to find another block, calling

  - `parseSourceElements` which calls `parseStatement` which calls `parseBlockStatement`, which parses the block, to find another block, calling

    - `parseSourceElements` which calls `parseStatement` which calls `parseBlockStatement`, which parses the block, to find another block, calling

      - ...

BOOM

### IE (and all other closed-source, like Opera)

...will remain a mystery, unless they feel the sudden urge to open their source or if an enterprising employee shared the internals with us. The two great engines above do it in the same fashion, so we can assume the other browsers do it similarly.

If a browser *doesn't* collapse, that's an interesting question, but one that this answer can't hope to *cough* answer.

Comment: Nice find. I wonder why they don't just incorporate a count/sleep/escape remedy? I have an object parser in a C++ service I made for WinXP long ago, I just simply kept count of how deep it went, when it went to far i began incorporating a sleep and when the sleep was over bearing (in other words, this parsing was taking more than 60 seconds) i escaped with a clean value of what was parsed, saved the unparsed portion to a repository variable making it loadable for parsing on user command. Seems like they should have already "been there/done that" without incident.

Comment: @SpYk3HH I guess because this is such an edge case, they didn't bother incorporating fancy techniques to avoid it. I vaguely recall seeing, somewhere in the webkit source, how they simply give up if a page has more than a thousand nested tables.

Comment: It's always the little things that the "creators" overlook that become the big "gotchyas" to us "coder-monkeys". lol

Answer (score 15):

Default implementation of [Recursive descend parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) while simple and elegant, parses every language grammar rule with one method. These methods call other methods recursively, so when you have too much nested rules, it exceeds the stack size. Chrome and Firefox both use such implementation of  interpreter.

You will notice that a lot of ' + ', while having nothing to do with scope, will cause the same exception:

```
+ + + + + + + + + ... // same error
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hpClk Are you sure of that? This is over 50000 `+` operators - no stack overflow error.

Comment: Correct arithmetic with constants is much easier to parse inline. Try it with var b = 1 instead of 1, it throws too.

Comment: @bfavaretto You got a +1 from me :) This sounds like a reasonable guess, however I'm having trouble accepting it since it takes no roots in the actual code. What functions in the V8 or SpiderMonkey code cause this and why?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I have no idea. But ghord's answer is so far the most plausible explanation. Here is a live test of what he just said, about addition with variables also throwing: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KypqG

Comment: +1 It's interesting that a StackOverflow while compiling is indistinguishable from a StackOverflow during execution by the reported error message.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You can see some mentions of this [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=15270#c11)